# Connecting from WSO2DSS to MongoDB, receiving error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ServerAddres.

Tags: mongodb, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I added the mongo Java driver and ds-connector-mongodb java driver jar files.

When I am connecting from WSO2DSS to MongoDB , I get the following error:

```
ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.core.DBDeployer} -  The MongoSampleDS.dbs service, which is not valid, caused {1}
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/ServerAddres.
```

Comment: Where did you put that file.. in the <CARBON_HOME>/repository/components/lib ??

Comment: yes,i added the jar files in same path only, is this jar files are sufficient or i need to add any other jar files or anything..

Answer (score 1):

The missing class looks like ServerAddress (I assume the missing "s" is a copy-paste issue) which is in the MongoDB Java driver ([mongo-java-driver](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver)).  Make sure mongo-java-driver-2.xx.jar is on the runtime classpath.  Note that the runtime classpath is not always the same as the compile time classpath.